# Siteminder Cookie deleted by Android Chrome before expiry

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, siteminder

We use an SSO solution, called Siteminder, that places a cookie on the device.  The expiry is set up for 5 days, but after 2 days the cookie is removed by Chrome and forcing the user to reauthenticate before the 5 day expiry. Do you know why it would do that?

The stock Android browser does not do that nor does the desktop version of Chrome expire the cookie prematurely.

I'm using the latest Android version of Chrome with no extensions.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Point taken...it's related but proly not Android specific since I see the same issue on iOS too.

Comment: Still not a programming question. It's a "why is this App (Chrome) doing something weird?" It's off-topic for StackOverflow and unlikely to get a response even if it doesn't get deleted for being off topic. You might want to check the Chrome bug file or see if there's another Stack Exchange site which is appropriate for questions about apps.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.  People post questions that aren't specifically programming questions all the time. Please take your editorial elsewhere.

Comment: It wasn't editorial, it was hopefully helpful advice. I was telling you that you're not likely to get an answer here and suggested where you might have better luck. The #1 Guideline for stuff not to ask here: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." SuperUser is the StackExchange site for general software questions.

Comment: I disagree that SuperUser is the correct forum. Software coding AND configuration is the realm of stack overflow. If it wasn't there wouldn't be a bunch of Git questions in this forum. Let's move on please.